# Find the largest three elements in an array

Tags: php

Find the largest three elements in an array, Given an array with all distinct elements, find the largest three elements. Expected time complexity is O(n) and extra space is O(1)

```
<?php 

$number = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10); 

print_r($number); 
echo "<br>";
$biggest_number_1 = 0; 
$biggest_number_2 = 0; 
$biggest_number_3 = 0;
 for ($i=0; $i < count($number); $i++){
    if($number[$i] > $biggest_number_1){
          $biggest_number_1 = $number[$i]; 
    } 

    if($number[$i] > $biggest_number_2 && $number[$i] != 10){ 
    $biggest_number_2 = $number[$i]; 
    }

    if($number[$i] > $biggest_number_3 && $number[$i] != 10 && $number[$i] != 9){ 
    $biggest_number_3 = $number[$i]; 
    }

} 
echo $biggest_number_1."<br>"; 
echo $biggest_number_2."<br>"; 
echo $biggest_number_3; 

?>
```

Comment: And what is your problem ?

Comment: set dynamic value hear :::: if($number[$i] > $biggest_number_2 && $number[$i] != 10){

Answer (score 1):

Simpliest way should be something like that :

```php
$number = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

rsort($number); // order array desc

// Just echo first 3 result in your array
echo $number[0]."<br>";
echo $number[1]."<br>";
echo $number[2];
```

Now if you want to loop through to your array to get the result, you can try this :

```php
$number = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$biggest_number_1 = $biggest_number_2= $biggest_number_3  = 0;

foreach ($number as $nb) {
    if ($nb > $biggest_number_1) {
        $biggest_number_3 = $biggest_number_2;
        $biggest_number_2 = $biggest_number_1;
        $biggest_number_1 = $nb;
    } else if ($nb > $biggest_number_2) {
        $biggest_number_3 = $biggest_number_2;
        $biggest_number_2 = $nb;
    } else if  ($nb > $biggest_number_3) {
        $biggest_number_3 = $nb;
    }
}

echo $biggest_number_1."<br>";
echo $biggest_number_2."<br>";
echo $biggest_number_3;
```

Comment: And do you have a reason to do it your way so we can understand please ?

Answer (score 0):

Just sort the array by ascending and take last 3 element of array.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:- This is perfectly work**

```
        $number=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
        $biggest_number_1 = $biggest_number_2= $biggest_number_3  = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($number) ; $i ++)
        {
            if ($number[$i] > $biggest_number_3 )
            {
                $biggest_number_1 = $biggest_number_2;
                $biggest_number_2 = $biggest_number_3 ;
                $biggest_number_3  = $number[$i];
            }
            else if ($number[$i] > $biggest_number_2)
            {
                $biggest_number_1 = $biggest_number_2;
                $biggest_number_2 = $number[$i];
            }
            else if ($number[$i] > $biggest_number_1){
                $biggest_number_1 = $number[$i];
            }
        }
        echo $biggest_number_1."<br>";
        echo $biggest_number_2."<br>";
        echo $biggest_number_3;
```

Comment: You shoud do the other way to ? First biggest_number_1, then 2 then 3, no ? If you test the code you will have 8 for 1, 9 for 2nd and 10 for 3nd biggest. with this exampel you will only go throught first if condition